# reload jquery mobile list view on click

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, mobile

I'm working on an iOS PhoneGap application. I currently get a RSS feed from Facebook thanks to jFeed, then it gets displayed on a listview : everything works great. I would like now to allow the user to reload the list view.

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-id="foo2" data-position="fixed">
             <h1>Actu BDA Audencia</h1>
            <a  href="#" onclick="$('#result').append(html);
                $('#result').listview("refresh");" data-icon="info" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button"  data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-right">Update</a>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="pull-to-refresh">test</div>
            <ul id="result" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d">
                </ul>

      </div>
 <script>
  jQuery(function() {

               jQuery.getFeed({
                              url: 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=360453900718092&format=atom10',
                              success: function(feed) {
                              $.mobile.loading( "show" );

                              var html = '';
                              var numjour= '';
                              var nummois = '';
                              var heure = '';
                              var newitem = '';

                              for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 10; i++) {

                              var item = feed.items[i];

                              numjour = item.updated.substr(8,2);
                              nummois = item.updated.substr(5,2);
                              nummois = nummois.replace('0', '');
                              heure = item.updated.substr(11,5);


                              newitem = item.description;





               html += '<li data-role="list-divider">'
               + numjour
               + ' '
               + months[nummois]
               + '<span class="ui-li-count">'
               + heure
               + '</span></li>'
               + '<li><p><br /><div class="tada">'
               + newitem
               + '</div></li></div>';

               }

               $('#result').append(html);
               $('#result').listview("refresh");
               $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
               }
               });
        });

 </script>
```

I added a "Update" button  to trigger the reload. Unfortunately, clicking on the button doesn't trigger anything. Could you help me on this?

Thank you very much,
David.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: $('#mylist').listview('refresh');

Check out the section "Updating lists": http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: I am already using this with the "Update" button : <a  href="#" onclick="$('#result').append(html);
                $('#result').listview("refresh");" data-icon="info" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button"  data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-right">Update</a> but this doesn't trigger the update....any help on how to solve this? thanks